# Expecting a deadlock when using select in a Go program

Tags: go, select, deadlock

The following Go program (extended from [this post](https://medium.com/rungo/anatomy-of-channels-in-go-concurrency-in-go-1ec336086adb), full source code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/oLIuTabkUw_t)) using unbuffered channels:

```
func service1(c chan string) {
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Ready to send on chan 1")
    c <- "Hello from service 1"
    fmt.Println("Sent on chan 1")
}

func service2(c chan string) {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Ready to send on chan 2")
    c <- "Hello from service 2"
    fmt.Println("Sent on chan 2")
}

func service3(c chan string) {
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Ready to receive on chan 3")
    res := <- c
    fmt.Println("Response from service main", res, time.Since(start))
}


func main() {
    fmt.Println("main() started", time.Since(start))

    chan1 := make(chan string)
    chan2 := make(chan string)
    chan3 := make(chan string)

    go service1(chan1)
    go service2(chan2)
    go service3(chan3)

    select {
    case res := <-chan1:
        fmt.Println("Response from service 1", res, time.Since(start))
    case res := <-chan2:
        fmt.Println("Response from service 2", res, time.Since(start))
    case chan3 <- "Hello from main":
        fmt.Println("Sent to service 3")
    }
    
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    
    fmt.Println("main() stopped", time.Since(start))
}
```

outputs:

```
main() started 0s
Ready to send on chan 2
Sent on chan 2
Response from service 2 Hello from service 2 2s
Ready to receive on chan 3
Ready to send on chan 1
main() stopped 7s
```

I would have expected `service1` and `service3` to lead to a deadlock since the `select` statement in `main` would have chosen the second case. However, the two goroutines neither block nor execute entirely (since the final print is not reflected in the output).

My understanding of the [select statement semantics](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) is that the receive on `chan1` and the send on `chan3` should not be executed although their operands are evaluated. Kindly correct if wrong, and help shed some light on this behavior. Thank you!

Comment: main just exits after the select statement and when main exits the program ends, no matter what. Also, for a deadlock *all* goroutines have to be blocked, but the main goroutine isn't.

Comment: Ah, I see! I have missed this important information, that a deadlock is defined by _all_ goroutines being blocked.

Comment: @andre_c Are there deadlocks that *don't* involve *every* member? "In concurrent computing, a deadlock is a state in which **each** member of a group waits for another member, including itself, to take action ..." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock

Comment: The go runtime isn't smart enough to determine whether or not a particular goroutine will eventually be woken up or not, and indeed this problem might be unsolvable in general as it sounds quite similar to the halting problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `select` statement is a blocking statement and will wait for atleast one of the statements to get evaluated successfully. So in the above example since `service2` has the least sleep time `(2 seconds)`, it gets executed first and the select statement gets exited.

Now you are waiting for 5 seconds. But this doesn't execute `service1` and `service3` because the `select` statement has already exited and there is no receiving go-routines for `service1` and `service3`.

With a simple `for` loop, you can wait till all the go-routines are executed. I have updated the full source code with this change [here](https://play.golang.org/p/1yYxW_I4pXJ). Even with the `for` loop there won't be any deadlock, because select statement ensures that there will only one statement running at a given time. If two statements are ready to execute, then one of them is chosen randomly.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var start time.Time

func init() {
    start = time.Now()
}

func service1(c chan string) {
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Ready to send on chan 1")
    c <- "Hello from service 1"
    fmt.Println("Sent on chan 1")
}

func service2(c chan string) {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Ready to send on chan 2")
    c <- "Hello from service 2"
    fmt.Println("Sent on chan 2")
}

func service3(c chan string) {
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Ready to receive on chan 3")
    res := <-c
    fmt.Println("Response from service main", res, time.Since(start))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main() started", time.Since(start))

    chan1 := make(chan string)
    chan2 := make(chan string)
    chan3 := make(chan string)

    go service1(chan1)
    go service2(chan2)
    go service3(chan3)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        select {
        case res := <-chan1:
            fmt.Println("Response from service 1", res, time.Since(start))
        case res := <-chan2:
            fmt.Println("Response from service 2", res, time.Since(start))
        case chan3 <- "Hello from main":
            fmt.Println("Sent to service 3")
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("main() stopped", time.Since(start))
}
```

Also waiting for child go-routines to complete can be better accomplished by using [sync.WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup)